# Change culture of Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, localization, silverlight-4.0, culture

I am working on a Silverlight app at the moment.  I have a few datagrids/textblocks where I use standard binding to show values, some of which are dates. e.g.

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Agent"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UpdateTime, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Update Time"/>
  </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastUpdatedTime}"/>
```

This binds fine but the dates are always shown as US style (m/d/y) whereas I want to show them UK style (d/m/y).  I have tried setting the culture using both the HTML tags on the page hosting the application

```
<param name="uiculture" value="en-GB" />
<param name="culture" value="en-GB" />
```

and on `Application_Start` of my Silverlight application

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

but neither of these make any difference.  I have a custom class that implements `IValueConverter` interface, I added a breakpoint on the Convert method and the CultureInfo parameter that is passed in is en-US, how do I change the culture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following line to the constructor of my form fixed this issue:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

From http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value from code kind of goes against the MVVM and dependency property approach: you might want to see this SO article:
[How to switch UI Culture of data binding on the fly in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992007/how-to-switch-ui-culture-of-data-binding-on-the-fly-in-silverlight)

Answer (score -1):

In the Converter use the below code

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
return value.ToString(ci);
```

Comment: Would I need to use a converter for each DataColumn/TextBlock that displays a date?

Comment: yes. But if you want to use global, In the MainPage constructor or Loaded event use below (No need for converter here)

 CultureInfo en = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = en;

Comment: As I said in my initial post i've already tried setting the CurrentCulture in the Application_Start event and it doesn't change how the dates are shown.